# Developer Center on Sitecore

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore7.5

I am using Sitecore 7.5 and I realized the module called Developer Center has disappeared.  On Sitecore 7.2 the module was in Development Tools Section, but in this new version, this module does not exists anymore.  Anybody know if there are another module with this functionality or I need to do something to replace it?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

Developer Center was discontinued in Sitecore 7.5, but it can be accessed by visiting http://example.com/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=IDE

Please refer to the full article on this by [Robbert Hock](http://www.newguid.net/sitecore/2015/sitecore-8-enable-developer-center-xpath-builder-file-explorer/).

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour that was in Developer Center has largely been replaced by the "Sitecore Rocks" extension for Visual Studio:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/44a26c88-83a7-46f6-903c-5c59bcd3d35b/

It also includes other features, for managing search indexes, looking at merged config files etc.

-- Edited to add --

Based on the comment below, I'd suggest you investigate this marketplace module. It doesn't explicitly say it supports 7.5 (and I don't have an instance available to test it right now) but it's possible that it might work, or that it can be made to work:

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Code_Editor.aspx

Comment: But, when an end user with a sitecore access need to modify a simple thing into a cshtml for example (like a css class), I can't force him to install a VS. On Sitecore 7.2 the Developer Center module allows you to modify layouts in the same sitecore desktop... This is the functionality I need to.

Comment: I understand your issue. But I think Sitecore have removed the behaviour because they want us to follow a more structured workflow.But you could try the module suggested above. It may work for you.

Comment: The issue with an end user modifying files on the Production environment means it's no longer in your source control. I think it would be recommended to use Rendering Parameters to allow some customization instead, or more advanced users using the HTML view of the Rich Text Field.

Comment: Anything an editor could ever need to edit should be a made a field in Sitecore. An editor should never need to edit cshtml/aspx/ascx/xslt, etc. files. This is the point of having a CMS. Also, as Jerm mentioned above, in a best practice environment, changes to project files should always go through some kind of workflow, and should never be edited directly on the production environment.